# How to charge for a version update for iOS application

Tags: ios, app-store

Is it possible to charge for a new version of the iOS application? Is it linked to the major version update for the application?

My application is at present at version 1.8 and the new version is almost a rewrite and I would like it to be a paid update to the next version.

If I bump version to 2.x, will that automatically become a paid update? Else what is the way to accomplish a paid update?

Comment: Release it as version 2.0 and tell your users to buy your app, now at version two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want EVERY USER, including your current users to pay for the new version, you will need to submit it as a new application. Current users will download the update for FREE. NEW users, if you change the price tier, will pay for the application. And no, the update will not automatically become a paid update. Updates are free to existing users.

You can however create an in-app purchase to unlock new features. This would ensure that even current users would need to pay for the "updates" as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can you also confirm if I submit it as a new application, then there would not be any automatic way to migrate data from the old app to the new app since they are two different applications?

Comment: You could send out redemption codes, but thats not an optimal idea. Other than that, there's no way to migrate users over unless you had like a server that housed current users information of some sort.